# Does T-Money card expire?

Tags: public-transport, south-korea

Similar to [the question on Shanghai subway card](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/73447/does-shanghai-subway-card-expire-after-not-using-for-a-while), does South Korea's T-Money card expire after not being used for a while?

Because I will enter the country again and again, I don't consider refunding, which costs me some charges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I have not found an official statement yet, many people on the Web insist that empirically there is no expiration.

- http://eatlah.blogspot.jp/2011/08/getting-around-seoul-with-t-money-card.html

> #### Can I get a refund for the remaining balance?
>
> T-Money cards have **no expiration date** and the unused balance will remain on your card until the entire amount is used up. You can receive a refund for the balance on your card at convenience stores like GS25 that charges KRW 500 (RM 1.43) fee and the card price of KRW 2,500 is not refundable.

- http://www.talktomeinkorean.com/blog/t-money/

> Or, you can just keep the T-money and the money on it for the next time you come to Korea because it NEVER expires!!

- https://www.reddit.com/r/korea/comments/14vrg2/tmoney_expiration/

> My sister lives in China, and her T-money card from 4 years ago still worked.

So for the time being let me make this question resolved as it has no expiration.

Answer (score 6):

I checked my T-Money card, obtained in Daejeon subway (but this doesn't matter and the card works fine anywhere). There is no mention of expiration date on it, and no mention of any date except the month it was issued.

In addition, the card had never been deactivated when I was not using it for a long time (about one year).

Note also that T-money cards can be recharged in any subway station, as well as in the ubiquitous convenient stores (GS25, CU, 7/11, etc...) in a few seconds.